# Waiting for data table to load after click / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to read the data table from the Indian Central Pollution Controal Board using selenium/python. Here is an example of [output](https://app.cpcbccr.com/ccr/#/caaqm-dashboard-all/caaqm-view-data-report/%2522%257B%255C%2522parameter_list%255C%2522%253A%255B%257B%255C%2522id%255C%2522%253A5%252C%255C%2522itemName%255C%2522%253A%255C%2522NH3%255C%2522%252C%255C%2522itemValue%255C%2522%253A%255C%2522parameter_311%255C%2522%257D%255D%252C%255C%2522criteria%255C%2522%253A%255C%252224%2520Hours%255C%2522%252C%255C%2522reportFormat%255C%2522%253A%255C%2522Tabular%255C%2522%252C%255C%2522fromDate%255C%2522%253A%255C%252201-01-2018%2520T00%253A00%253A00Z%255C%2522%252C%255C%2522toDate%255C%2522%253A%255C%252231-12-2021%2520T16%253A41%253A59Z%255C%2522%252C%255C%2522state%255C%2522%253A%255C%2522Andhra%2520Pradesh%255C%2522%252C%255C%2522city%255C%2522%253A%255C%2522Amaravati%255C%2522%252C%255C%2522station%255C%2522%253A%255C%2522site_1406%255C%2522%252C%255C%2522parameter%255C%2522%253A%255B%255C%2522parameter_311%255C%2522%255D%252C%255C%2522parameterNames%255C%2522%253A%255B%255C%2522NH3%255C%2522%255D%257D%2522).
I am essentially following the approach presented here:  https://github.com/RachitKamdar/Python-Scraper.

Thanks to @Prophet, I was able to read data from the first page ([Select element using XPATH with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993478/select-element-using-xpath-with-python)) but  I cannot get selenium to wait for the data table to reload when switching to page 2.
I tried to add a webdriverwait instruction but this does seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here is what I tried to do

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("select").send_keys("100")
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0_paginate']/span/a")))

maxpage = int(browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0_paginate']/span/a")[-1].text)

i = 1
while i < maxpage + 1:
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0_paginate']/span/a[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(i)).click()


    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"DataTables_Table_0_wrapper"))) 

    #this works ok for page 1
    #this does not wait after the click for the data table to update. As a result res is wrong for page 2 [empty].

    res = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
    soup = soup.find(id = 'DataTables_Table_0')
    ...
    i = i + 1
```

Update 1:
Following Prophet's suggestion, I made the following modification:

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("select").send_keys("100")
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"DataTables_Table_0_wrapper")))
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0_paginate']/span/a")))
maxpage = int(browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0_paginate']/span/a")[-1].text)
print(maxpage)
i = 1
while i < maxpage + 1:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"DataTables_Table_0_wrapper")))
    res = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
    soup = soup.find(id = 'DataTables_Table_0')

    if i == 1:
        data = getValsHtml(soup)
    else:
        data = data.append(getValsHtml(soup))
    print(i)
    print(data)
    i = i + 1
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[@class="paginate_button next"]').click()
```

This still crashes on page 2 (data is empty). In addition, data should contain 100 items from page 1 but only contains 10. The maxpage number is correct (15).

Update 2:

here is the whole script after incorporating Prophet's recommendations [original script follows https://github.com/RachitKamdar/Python-Scraper].
This only retrieves 10 points from the first page and fails to switch to the next page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

def getValsHtml(table):
    data = []
    heads = table.find_all('th')
    data.append([ele.text.strip() for ele in heads])
    rows = table.find_all('tr')

    for row in rows:

        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols]) # Get rid of empty values                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    data.pop(1)
    data = pd.DataFrame(data[1:],columns = data[0])
    return data


def parameters(br,param):
    br.find_element_by_class_name("list-filter").find_element_by_tag_name("input").send_keys(param)
    br.find_elements_by_class_name("pure-checkbox")[1].click()
    br.find_element_by_class_name("list-filter").find_element_by_tag_name("input").clear()


timeout = 60
url = 'https://app.cpcbccr.com/ccr/#/caaqm-dashboard-all/caaqm-landing/data'
chdriverpath="/net/f1p/my_soft/chromedriver"
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="{}".format(chdriverpath), chrome_options=option)
browser.get(url)

station="Secretariat, Amaravati - APPCB"
state="Andhra Pradesh"
city="Amaravati"

sd=['01', 'Jan', '2018']
ed=['31', 'Dec', '2021']
duration="24 Hours"


WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"toggle")))

browser.find_elements_by_class_name("toggle")[0].click()
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("input").send_keys(state)
browser.find_element_by_class_name("options").click()
browser.find_elements_by_class_name("toggle")[1].click()
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("input").send_keys(city)
browser.find_element_by_class_name("options").click()
browser.find_elements_by_class_name("toggle")[2].click()
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("input").send_keys(station)
browser.find_element_by_class_name("options").click()
browser.find_elements_by_class_name("toggle")[4].click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name("filter").find_element_by_tag_name("input").send_keys(duration)
browser.find_element_by_class_name("options").click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name("c-btn").click()
for p in ['NH3']:
    print(p)
    try:
        parameters(browser,p)
    except:
        print("miss")
        browser.find_element_by_class_name("list-filter").find_element_by_tag_name("input").clear()
        pass
browser.find_element_by_class_name("wc-date-container").click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name("month-year").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("{}".format(sd[1].upper())).click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name("year-dropdown").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("{}".format(int(sd[2]))).click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="{}"]'.format(int(sd[0]))).click()
browser.find_elements_by_class_name("wc-date-container")[1].click()
browser.find_elements_by_class_name("month-year")[1].click()
browser.find_elements_by_id("{}".format(ed[1].upper()))[1].click()
browser.find_elements_by_class_name("year-dropdown")[1].click()
browser.find_element_by_id("{}".format(int(ed[2]))).click()
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[text()="{}"]'.format(int(ed[0])))[1].click()
browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")[-1].click()


next_page_btn_xpath = '//a[@class="paginate_button next"]'
actions = ActionChains(browser)

#This is how you should treat the Select drop down                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("select"))
select.select_by_value('100')

WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer"]')))
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0_paginate']/span/a")))

maxpage = int(browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0_paginate']/span/a")[-1].text)


i = 1
while i < maxpage + 1:
    res = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
    soup = soup.find(id = 'DataTables_Table_0')

    if i == 1:
        data = getValsHtml(soup)
    else:
        data = data.append(getValsHtml(soup))
    print(i)
    print(data)
    i = i + 1

    #scroll to the next page btn and then click it                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    next_page_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath(next_page_btn_xpath)
    actions.move_to_element(next_page_btn).perform()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,next_page_btn).click()

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0_paginate']/span/a[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(i)).click()
```

Try clicking on this element:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[@class="paginate_button next"]').click()
```

It's simply next page button and it fill not change per page you are on.
Also, instead of

```
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"DataTables_Table_0_wrapper")))
```

Try this

```
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer"]')))
```

This element will be same for all the pages while that you trying to use defined for first page only.
**UPD**
The correct code should be like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

next_page_btn_xpath = '//a[@class="paginate_button next"]'
actions = ActionChains(driver)

#This is how you should treat the Select drop down
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select"))
select.select_by_value('100')

WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer"]')))

maxpage = int(browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0_paginate']/span/a")[-1].text)

i = 1
while i < maxpage + 1:
    res = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
    soup = soup.find(id = 'DataTables_Table_0')

    if i == 1:
        data = getValsHtml(soup)
    else:
        data = data.append(getValsHtml(soup))
    print(i)
    print(data)
    i = i + 1
    
    #scroll to the next page btn and then click it
    next_page_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_page_btn_xpath)
    actions.move_to_element(next_page_btn).perform()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,next_page_btn).click()
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this does not seem to work. I have updated my original post with more information

Comment: I will try to help you more, but currently I am not near the computer

Comment: Thanks. I also tried to replace the WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"DataTables_Table_0_wrapper"))) as you suggested but this does not change the outcome.

Comment: You did not do what I wrote you. I will update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Now I see that you tried to select a value from the drop down Select. I corrected that issue. Now, when you will have 100 results per page you will have to scroll down in order to click to the next page. I added that too.

Comment: Also, I see that site often getting stuck in "loading". In this case I think you have to refresh the page. But this resets the results per page selection to the default 10.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still getting some errors unfortunately and it's still only retrieving 10 items.

Comment: ` File "test2.py", line 124, in <module>
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,next_page_btn).click()
  File "/net2/f1p/miniconda3/envs/workstation/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/net2/f1p/miniconda3/envs/workstation/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)`

Comment: `  File "/net2/f1p/miniconda3/envs/workstation/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'value' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
`

Comment: Lets understand step by step. Does the first part of the code select 100 results per page? You should see that visually.

Comment: Yes it does. I can see that 100 entries displayed

Comment: I found another way to download the data that does not require selenium. Thank you for your help.